# Spring Data Rest HAL Response Format problem with Hibernate Lazy Initialization Objects

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, hateoas

**Technology stack:** Spring Boot (2.3.1.RELEASE),Spring Data JPA, Sprign Data Rest (3.3.1 RELEASE), Hibernate (5.4.17 Final), PostgresQL.
I have the parent entity **ProductEntity** :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class ProductEntity {

    @NotNull
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    private UUID id;

    @JsonProperty("productType")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "productEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, optional = false)
    private ProductTypeEntity productTypeEntity;
}
```

End the child entity **ProductTypeEntity** :

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_type")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer"})
public class ProductTypeEntity extends BaseEntity implements RootAware<ProductEntity> {
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String type;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String brand;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private ProductEntity productEntity;

    @Override
    public ProductEntity root() {
        return productEntity;
    }
}
```

End there is one Spring Data REST Repository **ProductRepository** :

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "products", path = "products")
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductEntity, UUID> {

}
```

The **main problem** is when I request **GET http://localhost:8081/api/v1/products** I recevice additional field **content** under **productType** that is completely redundant and prevents from adequate parsing of response :

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "products": [
            {
                "productType": {
                    "content": {
                        "type": "type1",
                        "brand": "brand1"
                    }
                }
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/products/6b0e375e-4d2d-41af-b42f-989859652c81"
                    },
                    "productEntity": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/products/6b0e375e-4d2d-41af-b42f-989859652c81"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/products"
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/profile/products"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

But when I change the productTypeEntity from **LAZY** TO **EAGER** :

```
@JsonProperty("productType")
@ToString.Exclude
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "productEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, optional = false)
private ProductTypeEntity productTypeEntity;
```

I receive the correct response without **content** field:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "products": [
            {
                "productType": {
                    "type": "type1",
                    "brand": "brand1",
                    "_links": {
                        "productEntity": {
                            "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/products/6b0e375e-4d2d-41af-b42f-989859652c81"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/products/6b0e375e-4d2d-41af-b42f-989859652c81"
                    },
                    "productEntity": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/products/6b0e375e-4d2d-41af-b42f-989859652c81"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/products"
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8081/api/v1/profile/products"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

The main question is what is the reason behind this behavior. I cannot adopt and use it becasue I cannot understand its nature and whether it is workaround or no.

Comment: When you GET `/api/v1/products`, do you want to include the value from `ProductType` (if not under `content`) or exclude?

Comment: @yejianfengblue I want to include ProductType, but not under content. The desired response is the second one listed above. I just need to 100% sure abount its nature and possible consequences.

Comment: Now that you always want Product contains ProductType value, why set fetch to lazy?